# Get only associations of associations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm currently working on a project where I have 3 models with a child and parent structure.

`City` has multiple `Location`s which has multiple `Stone`s. Each `Stone` only has one `Location` as parent and each `Location` only has one `City` as parent.

Now, I want to create a list of all `Stones` that 'belong' (through a `Location`) to a specific `City`. How would I retrieve all these associations, without having to do the following:

```
City.find({
  where: {
    id: 1337
  },
  include: [{
    model: Location,
    include: [{
      model: Stone
    }]
  }]
})
.then((city) => {
  city.stones = [].concat.apply([], city.locations.map(location => location.stones));
});
```

I'm trying to find out if there's a "SQL only" solution, so not retrieving data / having to execute JavaScript to generate this array.